# Continuous variable (1-100 scale) logistic function fitting

Tags: logistic, scales, sigmoid-curve

I've been working with a dataset where there are judgments of brightness from 1-100 (1= less bright) for 5 different brightness categories.

| patient | Brightness level | Judgment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 4 | 80 |
| 1 | 5 | 99 |
| 1 | 2 | 30 |
| 1 | 3 | 67 |
| 2 | 2 | 35 |
| 2 | 5 | 98 |
| 2 | 1 | 17 |
| 2 | 4 | 76 |
| 2 | 3 | 67 |

What I observe so far is that some subjects use the scale in a more binary way (i.e., choosing the end points 10 vs 90s), and others use it without that bias (i.e., making use of the whole scale). I'm trying to fit a logistic function but I am having a conceptual issue. The crossover point changes depending on how subjects used the scale. What are some of the free parameters that I can use here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have 4 options you can evaluate.  There are more than this, but these are first ones I would try.

1. Baseline:  Treat the person's individual response as part of the error term and regress judgement against brightness level.  This has the disadvantages that you stated.
2. Scale the judgement to the mean judgement for each person.
3. Scale the judgement to the mean judgement, but on the logistic scale.  It is often helpful to scale numbers constrained to [0,1] (or 0-100) using the logistic transform before performing linear operations.
4. Take a generalized mixed model approach with a random intercept on the logistic scale to account for differences between people.

Options are encoded below in R:

```r
dataf <- data.frame(p = c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5)),
                    b = factor(rep(1:5, times = 2)),
                    y = c(10, 30, 67, 80, 99,17, 35, 67, 76, 98))

# baseline - treat person as part of the error in the analysis

dataf$ydefault <- dataf$y/100
glm2 <- glm(ydefault ~ b, data = dataf, family = quasibinomial(link = "logit"))
summary(glm2)
plot(glm2, which = 2)

# option 1 - judgement relative to mean judgement

dataf$y1 <- dataf$y / rep(c(by(dataf$y, dataf$p, mean)), each = 5)
lm1 <- lm(y1 ~ b, data = dataf)
summary(lm1)
plot(lm1, which = 2)

# option 2 - judgement relative to mean judgement on a logistic scale

dataf$y2 <- plogis(qlogis(dataf$y/100) / rep(c(by(qlogis(dataf$y/100), dataf$p, mean)), each = 5))
glm1 <- glm(y2 ~ b, data = dataf, family = quasibinomial(link = "logit"))
summary(glm1)
plot(glm1, which = 2)

# option 3 - generalized mixed model with a random intercept by person and logistic link (quasibinomial family not allowed)

require(lme4)
glme1 <- lme4::glmer(ydefault ~ (1|p) + b, data = dataf, family = gaussian(link = "logit"))
summary(glme1)
plot(glme1)
```

Comment: Wow, this is extremely helpful! Thank you!